# JavaScript slice text content and wrap first word in <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am converting the following jQuery code to vanilla JavaScript and have become stuck on the final bit.

You will see in my snippet with the vanilla JS code, the span wrapped word is being inserted before the first word instead of replacing it.

Am I incorrectly using the `insertAdjacentHTML` function?

**jQuery**

```
var node = $(".content h1").contents().filter(function () {
  return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
  text = node.text(),
  first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));

if(!node.length)
  return;
        
node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
node.before('<span>' + first + '</span>');
```

```js
const splitHeadings = (() => {
  let node = document.querySelector(".content h1");

  if (node) {
    let content = node.textContent.trim();
    let first = content.slice(0, content.indexOf(" "));
    node.childNodes[0] = content.slice(first.length);
    console.log(first);
    console.log(content);
    first = `<span>${first}</span>`;
    node.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", first);
  }
})();
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sample string with multiple words</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not inserting but just replacing

Using map

```js
const splitHeadings = (() => {
  let node = document.querySelector(".content h1");

  if (node) {
    let content = node.textContent
      .trim()
      .split(" ")
      .map((word,i) => i===0 ? `<span>${word}</span>` : word);
    node.innerHTML = content.join(" ")
  }
})();
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sample string with multiple words</h1>
</div>
```

Using regex

```js
const splitHeadings = (() => {
  let node = document.querySelector(".content h1");

  if (node) {
    let content = node.textContent
      .trim()
      .replace(/\w+/,match => `<span>${match}</span>`);
    node.innerHTML = content;
  }
})();
```

```css
h1 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sample string with multiple words</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is map preferred over regex or vice versa? I am learning JS as I go and would like to use best practices and efficient code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: regex is in this case likely faster. Map is more versatile if you wanted to change the third word too